# Chain tests in mocha framework with smart contract testing

Tags: javascript, hardhat, testing, ethereumj, mocha

I am doing smart contract testing with hardat and mocha framework. Suppose I have two following `it` blocks testing contract A.

```
it('test1', () => {
  contractA.updateValue(val);
  // some other testing code
});
it('test2', () => {
  contractA.useUpdatedValue();
  // some other testing code
});
```

Here, `contracA` is defined in the global scope. Is there a way to persist the smart contract state in `test1` and then do `test2` to use the updated state of the smart contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap them in a one describe block and inside put a before block and inside that deploy those contracts.

Here is one of my repos to show how I do it: https://github.com/Kuly14/DJED/blob/main/test/unit/StableCoin.test.ts#L8

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.